# Return Formatted Text Using html() or text() Methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard.js

I am using clipboard.js plugin in order to copy/paste text (code snippets) from webpage. The plugin works fine actually, however I would like to paste the text of an element in same formatting it is displaying on the website. Is there any way to get such result? I using html() or text() methods to get the required text.

HTML

```
<input class="copy" type="button" value="copy" />
<pre class="snippet">
      #wrapper {
          height: 100px;
          width: 100px;
      }
      #wrapper {
          height: 100px;
          width: 100px;
      }
</pre>
```

JQuery

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var clipboard = new Clipboard('.copy', {
      text: function() {
          return $(".snippet").text();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: not really clear what you are asking. textNodes only inherit syle from their containers

Comment: @charlietfl you are wrong, I have applied the querySelector() method and perfectly did what I wanted

Comment: no idea what that means ... everything inside the `<pre>` is text , can't style text directly. Again, it's not clear what you are wanting to do

Comment: when the page rendered I can manually copy the code from and paste with formatting, and wanted to get the same result by copying the code using the plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have applied the querySelector method, and it solved the issue, now copied texts are being paste with formatting same as I see them on page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clipboard = new Clipboard('.copy', {
        target: function() {
            return document.querySelector('.snippet');
        }
    });
});
```